# Windows 10 fresh install, takes a while each boot to connect to internet

Tags: networking, windows-10, boot

Fresh Windows 10 home install on new build.  When I boot, it takes a good 30 seconds to connect to the internet (in the interim shows the yellow ! triangle on the network icon).

A little lost here, this is a pretty annoying thing to wait for on each boot.  I'm not even sure where to start diagnosing this.

**When not connected on boot**
[image]

**When connected after 30seconds +**
[image]

**OS**
Windows 10 Home
Version 1607
OS Build 14393.969

**Mobo**
Asus Prime Z270-K

**Network Driver**
Intel Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V
File version: 12.15.23.8

Comment: Perhaps some other program is hogging resources when booting up? Take a look at msconfig and see if this is the case

Comment: Very slow network router / DHCP server? Try changing to a static IP (& config, gateway dns, etc) for a little testing, see if it's just as slow still